# non-countable subset of $\mathbb 2^{\mathbb Z}$ with finite pairwise intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

Does a non countable subset of the power-set of $\mathbb Z$ exist so that the intersection of any two elements is a finite set?

If we ask for the sets to be pairwise disjoint then the answer is a clear no. I'm pretty stumped, something which may be helpful is that the number of finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$ is countable.

Comment: (it's not quite a duplicate, but you can just take a bijection of $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ to get the result from the other answer)

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, thanks.